# How to change file encoding table in java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, codepages, file-encodings

I have my code to check encoding table:

```
System.out.println("enc. table: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding") +
          "enc. table: "+new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()).getEncoding() + 
          "enc. table:" + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name());
```

When I start my from windows I get text file with cp1250, when I start from my embedded system I get text file with cp852. In windows I have set code page 852. In Eclipse I have set cp852. Some solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Platform default character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581985/platform-default-character-encoding)

Comment: How to change all this settings grammatically from java. Is that possible?

Comment: you don't need to change it.  all the jdk classes which require an encoding allow you to specify it manually.  (and you can't reliably change the default value at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You should really be specifing the required encoding on the `OutputStreamWriter`.

```
new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "cp852");
```

You may also want to read Joels article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)