# Java text encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

I read lines from a .txt file into a `String` list. I show the text in a `JTextPane`. The encoding is fine when running from Eclipse or NetBeans, however if I create a jar, the encoding is not correct. The encoding of the file is UTF-8. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: How are you reading the file?  Do you create a `new InputStreamReader(myFileInputStream, "UTF-8")` or are you creating a `FileInputStream` which uses the platform encoding?

Comment: I use `b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"))`.

Comment: have a look at [Java FileReader encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696626/java-filereader-encoding-issue)

Comment: proceed with what @MikeSamuel has suggested.

Comment: Answer from @MikeSamuel works. If you will leave an answer instead of a comment, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you're opening a reader using the [platform encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581985/platform-default-character-encoding).

You should manually specify the encoding whenever you convert between bytes and characters.  If you know that the appropriate encoding is UTF-8 you can open a file thus:

```
FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(myFile);
try {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFile, "UTF-8");
  // Maybe buffer reader and do something with it.
} finally {
  inputFile.close();
}
```

Libraries like [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IOExplained) can make this whole process easier..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your jar as

java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar xxx.jar